# Error when Join table with joinTable method

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2

I am joining search collection with category table with joinTable method.
I want to join category name and category url with search collection.
What i've tried is below

```
 $res = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
  $eav = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
  $nameattr = $eav->getAttribute('catalog_category', 'name');
  $nametable = $res->getTableName('catalog/category') . '_' . $nameattr->getBackendType();
  $nameattrid = $nameattr->getAttributeId();
$results->joinTable('catalog/category_product',
        'product_id=entity_id', array('single_category_id' => 'category_id'),
        null, 'left')
        ->groupByAttribute('entity_id')
        ->joinTable($nametable,
        "entity_id=single_category_id", array('single_category_name' => 'value'),
        "`$nametable`.attribute_id=$nameattrid", 'left');
```

This perfectly return category_name but how i can also insert category url in this join condition?

Comment: could you show us your full code including where `$nametable` and `$nameattrid` are defined.

Comment: @DavidManners  updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add one more join to include the attribute 'url_path'. With adding another join you will have to change how you join to work with aliases. The first parameter of the function `joinTable` allows for an array of the format `array('alias' => 'table')`

```
$res = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$eav = Mage::getModel('eav/config');
$nameattr = $eav->getAttribute('catalog_category', 'name');
$nametable = $res->getTableName('catalog/category') . '_' . $nameattr->getBackendType();
$nameattrid = $nameattr->getAttributeId();

$urlattr = $eav->getAttribute('catalog_category', 'url_path');
$urltable = $res->getTableName('catalog/category') . '_' . $urlattr->getBackendType();
$urlattrid = $urlattr->getAttributeId();
$results->joinTable('catalog/category_product',
    'product_id=entity_id', array('single_category_id' => 'category_id'),
    null, 'left')
    ->groupByAttribute('entity_id')
    ->joinTable(array('cat_name' => $nametable),
        "entity_id=single_category_id", array('single_category_name' => 'value'),
        "cat_name.attribute_id=$nameattrid", 'left')
    ->joinTable(array('cat_url' => $urltable),
        "entity_id=single_category_id", array('single_category_url' => 'value'),
        "cat_url.attribute_id=$urlattrid", 'left');
```

**NOTE:** I am not sure how this code will work with the different values for different stores. But the table `catalog_category_entity_varchar` does have a store_id column so you could easily add this to the join clause.

Comment: yes working great